# How to get the height of an NSTableCellView that uses autolayout

Tags: macos, nstableview, autolayout, nstablecellview

I have a view-based `NSTableView`.  I positioned the `textField` and other elements in an `NSTableCellView` in Interface Builder with autolayout.  How can I get the height for the cell based on its autolayout parameters?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) is the closest I have found to what I am looking for, but it is written for iOS and the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` method does not exist on `NSView`.

Comment: Conflict - iOS and `NSTableCellView`. Which do you really mean? OS X or `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @rmaddy I think he means OSX and `NSTableCellView`.  He references iOS in a tag (which I edited), but also says "but it is written for iOS" in reference to an answer that would otherwise be helpful.

Comment: Yes thanks, I meant Mac OS X/NSTableCellView.

Answer (score 6):

You could put the views inside your table cell view into a separate [`NSView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) (let's call this view `contentView`). Set Auto Layout constraints for the `contentView` so that it aligns to its parent view at the left (leading), top and right (trailing). Make sure the subviews of `contentView` resize their parent view. Create an `IBOutlet` on that view in your [`NSTableCellView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableCellView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclass. To calculate the height, call [`fittingSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/fittingSize) on `contentView` which should get you the *minimal* size of your subviews based on the constraints.